# Awk: how to print only between greater than or lesser than negative numbers

Tags: awk

I have a column of negative numbers, i want to print only between a range of negative numbers.
Ex: i want only above -50 and below -500
Col:

```
-1002
-50
-34
-56
-480
-4578
-53
...
```

Comment: Users on this platform are encouraged to share their attempts at solvering their problems

Comment: _above -50 and below -500_, really? Please, post the expected output and some work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk '{if ($1 < -50 &&  $1 > -500) print ;}' file
```